# Adding PayPal feature to Rails web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I was looking to add a feature that allows my users to send money to one another via PayPal or some other popular source that could handle such a request. As this is something I have yet to implement to a website I'm fairly new and would like to see if anyone could guide me in a direction with some suggestions/ideas on how to realize this. I thank all those in advance who take the time to try and assist in my learning the implementation of a new feature such as this.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the screencast & the article listed below:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics?view=asciicast ,
- http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/basic-paypal-checkout-processing-in-rails